# Reserve a part of memory

Tags: c, linker, processor, nrf52

Currently I am making some code for a Nordic nRF chip. I want to make it power efficient so I am experimenting with it. A part of that is turning memory sections off. So my goal is to power one block of RAM and the rest can turn off. And the data that I put in the section that is turned on I want to put in manually.

So here is my question:

How can I make my program not put data in a specific part of memory?
I understood via the linker but I am not sure.

I have tried looking online mostly for fixes with linkers but I still find it quite confusing.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I see at least two questions here and recommend to try and focus on one only. First question: How do I put data manually in data structures? Second question: How do I make sure that selected data structures end up in specific memory parts? By gut feeling I guess that you mostly want help with the second question. For the first question (which I recommend to ask separatly and after you got feedback or answers here) You probably want to elaborate what you mean by "put in manually". Good luck.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will look in to that.

Comment: More generic info to help you: [ask] and [mre]. I.e. you might want to show a little example program and describe which data or data structures you think of and what you need to do with them. Maybe the first question is already answered that way, and/or it will be a foundation for answers to the second.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.